# diascope - running command via cron

Tags: php, cron, centos, sox

I'm trying to run a diascope in a php script

```
[root@mvl vt-scripts]# cat test.php 
<?php

exec('/usr/bin/awk -f /root/virtual-tours-scripts/diascope/diascope -- -clean /center/datacenter/vt-scripts/169553_vtnb_script.txt > output.txt', $arr);
print_r($arr);
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
tail: output.txt: file truncated

diascope 0.2.1d (ms 2006-2015) slideshow generator
See http://diascope.sf.net for documentation and updates.

Error: executable program not found: sox
Please see the requirements for diascope in the release notes.
Giving up
```

Running the command directly in the terminal returns no error

Sox appears to be installed ok

```
[root@mvl vt-scripts]# sox --version
sox:      SoX v14.4.2
```

I'm using 
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Jul  9 2015 17:39:00)

any thoughts? thanks in advance!

Comment: What does `which sox` output? Are you planning on using `sox` with this?

Comment: [root@mvl bin]# which sox
/usr/local/bin/sox

yes, diascope executes the txt file and outputs an .sh file which contains a line which uses sox...

Comment: Is `/usr/local/bin` in the `$PATH` of the user running the `php` script? Why is `sox` manually installed instead of installed from the CentOS `sox` package?

Comment: [root@mvl vt-scripts]# ls /usr/local/bin
play  rec  sox  soxi
i installed it manually because i didn't know how to install it with yum

running it via cron i get this in mail root: which: no sox in (/usr/bin:/bin)

that was the source: http://techblog.netwater.com/?p=4

Comment: Do you need mp3 support in `sox`? Because that's what that is about. `yum install sox` will install it on CentOS 6 otherwise. In either case that `which` output is the problem. You don't have `/usr/local/bin` in your `$PATH` where your `php` runs. You need to fix that.

Comment: yes, i do need mp3... i remember this being the decision, yes in the first place because default was not supporting mp3... dunno if i set it right... PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin .. seems not to work... what am i missing?

Comment: Where did you set that?

Comment: /root/.bash_profile I modified this line, it was PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101369/discussion-between-dtmirror-and-etan-reisner).

Comment: Your cron-run php script isn't running a root shell. That setting won't affect it. You need to set it in the script or in the cron job/config itself.

Comment: i made it work after all.. i installed sox and ffmpeg with yum install and then created a link from /usr/bin to their default locations... seems to work.... too much headache... 
thanks a lot for your help Etan!

Comment: You made a link from where to where? If you installed the `sox` CentOS package then you shouldn't have needed to link anything for that version to work. And linking **anything** in the package managed locations (like `/usr/bin` is a **very** bad idea.

Comment: for sox it seems to be ok, but i have the same issue with ffmpeg, so i had to compile sources separately and make the link like this /usr/bin/ffmpeg -> /root/bin/ffmpeg

Comment: Right. That link is a **very** bad idea. Fixing the `$PATH` is a **much** better idea.

Comment: tried to add that /root/bin to path but still don't work, so that's a workaround i'm happy with atm, i'm behind my work with 2 days now

Comment: You added it to the root user's path. That's not where you need it. You need it in the cron environment.